# Unir elementos repetidos en una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Intento conseguir que a partir del resultado de una función que me va retornando listas de palabras como la siguiente:

```
[('algo', 1), ('de', 1), ('una', 1), ('de', 1), ('una', 1), ('y', 1), ('otra', 1), ('cabeza', 1), ('', 1)]
```

que otra función me vaya recogiendo estas listas y me cree listas con las que son iguales, es decir que me de de resultado algo así:

```
[('una', 1), ('una', 1)]
[('de', 1), ('de', 1)]
[('algo', 1)]
[('y', 1)]
...
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Necesitariamos saber si has intentado algo, y si es asi donde estas teniendo el problema.

Comment: gracias! estoy aprendiendo coo funciona :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el módulo `collections` (estándar python) tienes la clase `Counter()` que te hace buena parte del "trabajo sucio".

A esa clase le pasas un iterable (en este caso tu lista) y va buscando en ella elementos repetidos. Te devuelve un diccionario cuyas claves son los elementos de la lista, y cuyos valores son el número de repeticiones de cada uno.

Por ejemplo:

```
>>> import collections
>>> l = [('algo', 1), ('de', 1), ('una', 1), ('de', 1), ('una', 1), ('y', 1), ('otra', 1), ('cabeza', 1), ('', 1)]
>>> collections.Counter(l)
Counter({('', 1): 1,
         ('algo', 1): 1,
         ('cabeza', 1): 1,
         ('de', 1): 2,
         ('otra', 1): 1,
         ('una', 1): 2,
         ('y', 1): 1})
```

Para obtener la lista que pides en la pregunta, basta usar este resultado proporcionado por `Counter` para crearla. Basta repetir cada elemento indicado en la clave el número de veces indicado en el valor:

```
>>> [[k]*v for k, v in collections.Counter(l).items()]
[[('algo', 1)],
 [('de', 1), ('de', 1)],
 [('una', 1), ('una', 1)],
 [('y', 1)],
 [('otra', 1)],
 [('cabeza', 1)],
 [('', 1)]]
```